# impementing a client that connects to the server

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have both a client and a server but when I run the server it gives me http://localhost: 0.0.0.0.8080 and I can't reach that website.

```
import socketio
sio = socketio.Client()
@sio.event
def connect():
    print (' connection established')
@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print(' disconnected from server')
sio.connect ('http://localhost:8080')
sio.emit('message', {'data':'my_data'})
sio.wait()

``
from aiohttp import web
import socketio

socket_io = socketio.AsyncServer()
app = web.Application()
socket_io.attach(app)

async def index(request):
    return web.Response(text='Hello world from socketio',content_type='text/html')

@socket_io.on('message')
def print_message(socket_id, data):
    print("Socket ID:' , socket_id")
    print("Data : ", data)
    app.router.add_get('/', index)

if __name__=='__main__':
    web.run_app(app)
``
```

Comment: check the url `http://localhost: 0.0.0.0.8080`. I think it will `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: When I connect in the browser to localhost:8080 I 404: Not Found